# Using fadein and append

Tags: javascript, jquery, fade

I am loading JSON data to my page and using `appendTo()` but I am trying to fade in my results, any ideas?

```
$("#posts").fadeIn();
$(content).appendTo("#posts");
```

I saw that there is a difference between `append` and `appendTo`, on the documents.

I tried this as well:

```
$("#posts").append(content).fadeIn();
```

***I got it, the above did the trick!***

But I get `"undefined"` as one of my JSON values.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

If you hide the content before you append it and chain the fadeIn method to that, you should get the effect that you're looking for.

```
// Create the DOM elements
$(content)
// Sets the style of the elements to "display:none"
    .hide()
// Appends the hidden elements to the "posts" element
    .appendTo('#posts')
// Fades the new content into view
    .fadeIn();
```

Comment: I'm trying $(elem).slideUp().appendTo(div).slideDown(); but it doesn't do it in order in FF5. I'm using slideUp's callback to then append and slideDown in order, but then append doesn't have a callback, so the element appears already visible.

Kent Fredric's answer addresses this issue, so I'm only concerned on the append being executed before the slide Down.

Comment: Kent's answer does address using animation methods like slideUp and slideDown with callbacks, but the OP only really needed an animation at the end of the method chain. Do you need further help?

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if I fully understand the issue you're having, but something like this should work:

HTML:

```
<div id="posts">
  <span id="post1">Something here</span>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var counter=0;

$.get("http://www.something/dir",
    function(data){
        $('#posts').append('<span style="display:none" id="post' + counter + ">" + data + "</span>" ) ;
        $('#post' + counter).fadeIn();
        counter += 1;
    });
```

Basically you're wrapping each piece of the content (each "post") in a span, setting that span's display to none so it doesn't show up, and then fading it in.

Comment: Excellent example of how to do simple things in a very complicated way. Sorry man ;)

Answer (score 4):

This should solve your problem I think.

```
$('#content').prepend('<p>Hello!</p>');
$('#content').children(':first').fadeOut().fadeIn();
```

If you are doing append instead then you have to use the :last selector instead.

Answer (score 3):

You have to be aware that the code doesn't execute linearly. The animated stuff can't be expected to halt code execution to do the animation and then return.

```
   commmand(); 
   animation(); 
   command();
```

This is because the animation uses set timeout and other similar magic to do its job and settimeout is non-blocking.

This is why we have callback methods on animations to run when the animation is done ( to avoid changing something which doesn't exist yet )

```
   command(); 
   animation( ... function(){ 
      command(); 
   });
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(output_string.html).fadeIn().appendTo("#list");
```

Answer (score 2):

assuming you have the following in the css defined:

```
.new {display:none}
```

and the javascript should be :

```
$('#content').append('<p class='new'>Hello!</p>');
$('#content').children('.new').fadeIn();
$('#content').children.removeClass('new');
$('#content').children('.new').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

First is convert received data to jQuery Object.
Second, hide it immediately.
Third, append it to a target node.
And, after this all, we can clearly use necessary animation, just like fadeIn :)

```
jNode = $("<div>first</div><div>second</div>");
jNode.hide();
$('#content').append(jNode);
jNode.fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 0):

im have a exprensive,for this:

```
$("dt").append(tvlst.ddhtml);
$("dd:last").fadeIn(700);
```

Comment: What's "exprensive"?

Answer (score 0):

**I tried what you said did the trick but is not working.
*it worked with the following code***

```
$("div").append("content-to-add").hide().fadeIn();
```