# jQuery append fadeIn

Tags: jquery

Similar to: [Using fadein and append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327682/using-fadein-and-append)

But the solutions there aren't working for me. I'm trying:

```
 $('#thumbnails').append('<li><img src="/photos/t/'+data.filename+'"/></li>').hide().fadeIn(2000);
```

But then the whole list fades in at once, not as each item is added. It looks like `hide()` and `fadeIn()` are being applied to `$('#thumbnails')` not the `<li>`. How would I get them to apply to that instead? This doesn't work either:

```
$('#thumbnails').append('<li stle="display:none"><img src="/photos/t/'+data.filename+'"/></li>').filter(':last').fadeIn(2000);
```

Other suggestions?

Answer (score 208, accepted):

Your first attempt is very close, but remember that `append()` is returning `#thumbnails`, not the item you just added to it.  Instead, construct your item first and apply the `hide().fadeIn()` before adding it:

```
$('#thumbnails')
    .append($('<li><img src="/photos/t/'+data.filename+'"/></li>')
        .hide()
        .fadeIn(2000)
    );
```

This uses the dollar function to construct the `<li>` ahead of time.  You could also write it on two lines, of course, if that makes it clearer:

```
var item = $('<li><img src="/photos/t/'+data.filename+'"/></li>')
    .hide()
    .fadeIn(2000);
$('#thumbnails').append(item);
```

**Edit:** Your second attempt is also almost there, but you need to use `children()` instead of `filter()`.  The latter only removes nodes from the current query; your newly-added item isn't in that query, but is a child node instead.

```
$('#thumbnails')
    .append('<li style="display:none"><img src="/photos/t/'+data.filename+'"/></li>')
    .children(':last')
    .hide()
    .fadeIn(2000);
```

Comment: Beautiful! Works perfectly. You wouldn't happen to know how to delay starting the fade until the thumbnail has finished loading too would you?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, but "how do I trigger a function when an image finishes loading" isn't a bad idea for a separate question. ;-)

Comment: I know, I just thought you were so smart we could kill two birds with one stone :p Oh well, Google provided a solution. Thanks again :)

Comment: If you still have the link handy, I'd love to see the technique.

Comment: Yeah, I have to agree that Ben seems quite smart to catch all that ;) Also, I agree that it would be nice to have the google solution in here IMHO.

Comment: @Rob & Ben: Hey guys, sorry I didn't see your comments earlier. I managed to dig up the code I used, I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: thanks for the example! It is `style` not  `stle`  :)

Answer (score 48):

```
$('<li><img src="/photos/t/'+data.filename+'"/></li>')
    .appendTo('#thumbnails')
    .hide().fadeIn(2000);
```

Comment: Sneaky...reversing the order. I like it.

Answer (score 32):

[Ben Blank's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978708/jquery-append-fadein/978731#978731) is good, but the fading, for me, is glitchy.  Try fading in *after* you append:

```
var item = $('<li><img src="/photos/t/'+data.filename+'"/></li>').hide();
$('#thumbnails').append(item);
item.fadeIn(2000);
```

Comment: I agree completely, this approach will avoid the one frame render that will cause a flicker... just that bit more finesse

Comment: Thanks - this fixed a glitch for me where the layout/positioning of the item that was about to appear was inconsistent when doing them both at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

Try it!

```
 $('#thumbnails').append(<li> your content </li>);
 $('#thumbnails li:last').hide().fadeIn(2000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('<li><img src="/photos/t/'+data.filename+'"/></li>').hide().appendTo('#thumbnails').fadeIn(2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I went with:

```
function onComplete(event, queueID, fileObj, response, info) {
    var data = eval('(' + response + ')');
    if (data.success) {
        $('#file-' + queueID).fadeOut(1000);
        var img = new Image();
        $(img).load(function () { // wait for thumbnail to finish loading before fading in
            var item = $('<li id="thumb-' + data.photo_id + '"><a href="#" onclick="deletePhoto(' + data.photo_id + ')" class="delete" alt="Delete"></a><a href="#" class="edit" alt="Edit"></a><div class="thumb-corners"></div><img class="thumbnail" src="/photos/t/' + data.filename + '" width=150 height=150/></li>');
            $('#thumbnails').append(item.hide().fadeIn(2000));).attr('src', '/photos/t/' + data.filename);
        } else {
            $('#file-' + queueID).addClass('error');
            //alert('error ' + data.errno); // TODO: delete me
            $('#file-' + queueID + ' .progress').html('error ' + data.errno);
        }
    }
}
```

This works with [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/). It uses jquery's `load` event to wait for the image to finish loading before it appears. Not sure if this is the best approach, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```html
var infoszoveg = '<div class="kosarba-info" style="display:none"><div class="notice"> A termék bekerült a kosaradba! » </div></div>';

$(infoszoveg).fadeIn(500).appendTo('.kosar-ikon');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#target').append($(serverResponseHTMLString).hide().fadeIn(1000));
```

Comment: Your answer contains code without explanation. It's better to include details about *how* your answer answers the question.