# Ajax loaded comment not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

My php file loops out each blog post in my database and also creates the comments section. The blogs post great. When I comment on the most recent blog post, the comment does not appear but it seems to add a line as the space expands, just does not include the comment. When I comment on the first post, it works great and exactly as expected. I can't figure out how to correct it. I thought it was a matter of add a .closest to the comment-block selector but that didn't seem to do the trick.

I appreciate any help or feedback!

PHP/HTML

```
<?php   // retrive post
     include('php/config.php');
    include ('php/function.php');
    dbConnect();

    $blog_query = mysql_query(
    'SELECT * 
    FROM Blog 
    ORDER BY DATE DESC');

    $date = date_create($row['DATE']);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($blog_query)): ?>

    <div class="post">
        <h2><?php echo $row['TITLE']?></h2>
        <h3><?php echo date_format($date, 'l, F j, Y')?></h3>
        <p><?php echo $row['CONTENT']?></p>
    </div>
    <h2>Comments.....</h2>
    <div class="comment-block">

<?php   // retrieve comments with post id
    $comment_query = mysql_query(
        "SELECT *
        FROM Comments
        WHERE BID = {$row['ID']}
        ORDER BY CID DESC
        LIMIT 15") or die(mysql_error());

        while($comment = mysql_fetch_array($comment_query)):?>

        <div class="comment-item">
            <div class="comment-post">
                <h3><?php echo $comment['UNAME'] ?> <span>said....</span></h3>
                <p><?php echo $comment['COMMENT']?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile?>
    </div>

    <h2>Submit new comment</h2>
    <!--comment form -->
    <form id="form" method="post"> 
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" name="BID" value="<?php echo $row['ID']?>">
            <label> <span>Display Name: *</span>
                <input id="uname" type="text" tabindex="1" name="commentName" required />
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label> <span>Comment: *</span>
                <textarea id="textarea" placeholder="Enter your comment here..." tabindex="2" name="commentMessage" required></textarea>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Comment">
        </div>
    </form>     


<?php endwhile?>    
</div>
```

Jquery/Ajax:

```
var form = $('form');
var submit = $('#submit');

form.on('submit', function(e) {
    // prevent default action
    e.preventDefault();
    // send ajax request
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/ajaxcomment.php',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: form.serialize(), //form serizlize data
        beforeSend: function(){
            // change submit button value text and disabled it
            submit.val('Submitting...').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        },
        success: function(data){
            // Append with fadeIn see http://stackoverflow.com/a/978731
            var item = $(data).hide().fadeIn(800);
            $('.comment-block').append(item);

            // reset form and button
            form.trigger('reset');
            submit.val('Submit Comment').removeAttr('disabled');
        },
        error: function(e){
            alert(e);
        }
    });
});
```

ajajcomment.php

```
<?php
if (isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] )):
include('config.php');
include('function.php');
dbConnect();

if (!empty($_POST['commentName']) AND !empty($_POST['commentMessage']) AND !empty($_POST      ['BID'])) {
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['commentName']);
    $comment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['commentMessage']);
    $BID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['BID']);

    mysql_query("
        INSERT INTO Comments
        (UNAME, BID, COMMENT)
        VALUES('{$name}', '{$BID}', '{$comment}')");            
}
?>

 <div class="comment-item">
<div class="comment-post">
    <h3><?php echo $name ?> <span>said....</span></h3>
    <p><?php echo $comment ?></p>
</div>
</div>

<?php
dbConnect(0);
endif?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What does "php/ajaxcomment.php" return when you post a comment? Pure HTML?

I'd make the "php/ajaxcomment.php" return JSON, for example:

```
<?php
/*
here you do what ever you do now,
Insert the new comment to database, etc
*/

// Then you return the inserted data:
$data = array(
  'UNAME' => $username,
  'COMMENT' => $comment,
);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
print json_encode( $data );
?>
```

..and change the ajax:

```
...
...
success: function(data){
    var commentItem = $('<div/>').addClass('comment-item');
    var commentPost = $('<div/>').addClass('comment-post');
    var user        = $('<h3/>').html( data.UNAME +'<span>said...</span>' );
    var comment     = $('<p/>').html( data.COMMENT );

    commentItem.html( commentPost.html( user + comment ) ).hide().fadeIn(800);

    $('.comment-block').append(commentItem);

    // reset form and button
    form.trigger('reset');
    submit.val('Submit Comment').removeAttr('disabled');
},
...
...
```

Comment: And I'd use <button id="submit" type="submit">Submit comment</button> instead of  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit comment"/> and in javascript you should handle this <button> element, like:
$('#submit').text('Submitting...');
..and to continue this same proposal, you should use .prop() instead of .attr(), so this would be:
$('#submit').text('Submitting...').prop('disabled',true);  and
$('#submit').text('Submit comment').prop('disabled,false);

More info in:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Comment: Kirbo, I appreciate the response. I edited my code to reflect your suggestion but had the same issue. I can't figure this out, the strange thing is that on submit, the second blog comments don't even get to the database, but the first blog works fine.

Comment: Could you maybe show the "php/ajaxcomment.php" file also? If not, try debugging it with Chrome Web Inspector or Firefox Firebug or something similar which shows you the request been made and the response it gets. Add into beginning of the "php/ajaxcomment.php" like:

    <?php
    print '<pre>';
    print_r( $_POST );
    die;
    ...
    ...


or:
    <?php
    get_defined_vars()
    die;
    ...
    ...

Comment: added php file. I will have to get back to this tomorrow. I truly appreciate your help!

Comment: only works on the first blog/comment section. On the second blog instance, it does not post to database or screen.