# Append does not work for appending text to an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

Similar to this question: 
[jQuery append fadeIn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978708/jquery-append-fadein)

But the solution isn't working for me.

Basically trying to ask the user their name and then append a greeting below.
Preferably on a fade in, I've tried a few solutions I came across here but to no avail.

The "document.name_form..etc) works fine when called inside an alert as well.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

```
function doit() {
    $('#item2').append( document.name_form.fname.value +"U WOT");  
}
```

(The function `doit` gets triggered from the html forms "onSubmit", and has triggered alerts etc successfully)

Code snippet:

```js
var greeting = "hello "
var div = document.getElementById('#item2');

function doit() {
  $('#item2').append(document.name_form.fname.value + "U WOT");
}


// alert(greeting + document.name_form.fname.value)
//
//
// $( " HEYTHERDUDE "  + document.name_form.fname.value).appendTo($( " #item2 " )); 
//
// div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + 'LOOK AT ME' + document.name_form.fname.value;
```

```css
/***************************/


/*****CONTAINER STYLES******/


/***************************/

body {
  background-color: #212130;
}

#container {
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  color: #c5c520;
  font-weight: 300;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 225px;
  max-width: 325px;
}


/***************************/


/*******INPUT STYLES********/


/***************************/

.input {
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
  border-color: #c5c520;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.2s;
  -o-transition: box-shadow 0.2s;
  transition: box-shadow 0.2s;
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  color: #c5c520;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.input:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -10px 20px -10px #131322;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -10px 20px -10px #131322;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -10px 20px border-right-width: 1px;
  border-left-color: #181825;
  border-right-color: #181825;
}

.input:focus {
  background-color: #191929;
}

.name_submit {
  color: #181825;
  background-color: #c5c520;
  border: none;
}

.submit_btn {
  display: none;
}

.question {
  display: block;
  bottom: 15px;
}


/***********************************/


/*******ITEM SPECIFIC STYLES********/


/***********************************/

#item1 {
  display: block;
}

#item2 {
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">


  <!-- WHAT IS YOUR NAME -->

  <div class="question" id="item1">
    <div class="text">
      <p>
        Before we get started, what is your name?
      </p>
    </div>
    <form name="name_form" action="" onSubmit="doit()">
      <input type="text" class="input" name="fname">
      <p></p>
      <input type="button" value="Submit" class="submit_btn">
    </form>
  </div>

  <!-- GREETING RE NAME -->
  <div class="question" id="item2">
    HI THERE
  </div>



</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.append()` should be used to add new DOM elements. To add text to an existing element, use `.text`.

```
function doit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#item2').text( function(i, oldtext) {
        return oldtext + $("form[name=name_form] input[name=fname]").val()+"U WOT";
    });
}
```

You also have to use `preventDefault()` to prevent the form from being submitted. To match this, I changed the `<form>` to:

```
<form name="name_form" action="" onSubmit="doit(event)">
```

Demo:

```js
var greeting = "hello "
var div = document.getElementById('#item2');

function doit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#item2').text(function(i, oldtext) {
    return oldtext + $("form[name=name_form] input[name=fname]").val() + "U WOT";
  });
}


// alert(greeting + document.name_form.fname.value)
//
//
// $( " HEYTHERDUDE "  + document.name_form.fname.value).appendTo($( " #item2 " )); 
//
// div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + 'LOOK AT ME' + document.name_form.fname.value;
```

```css
/***************************/


/*****CONTAINER STYLES******/


/***************************/

body {
  background-color: #212130;
}

#container {
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  color: #c5c520;
  font-weight: 300;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 225px;
  max-width: 325px;
}


/***************************/


/*******INPUT STYLES********/


/***************************/

.input {
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
  border-color: #c5c520;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.2s;
  -o-transition: box-shadow 0.2s;
  transition: box-shadow 0.2s;
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  color: #c5c520;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.input:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -10px 20px -10px #131322;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -10px 20px -10px #131322;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -10px 20px border-right-width: 1px;
  border-left-color: #181825;
  border-right-color: #181825;
}

.input:focus {
  background-color: #191929;
}

.name_submit {
  color: #181825;
  background-color: #c5c520;
  border: none;
}

.submit_btn {
  display: none;
}

.question {
  display: block;
  bottom: 15px;
}


/***********************************/


/*******ITEM SPECIFIC STYLES********/


/***********************************/

#item1 {
  display: block;
}

#item2 {
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">


  <!-- WHAT IS YOUR NAME -->

  <div class="question" id="item1">
    <div class="text">
      <p>
        Before we get started, what is your name?
      </p>
    </div>
    <form name="name_form" action="" onSubmit="doit(event)">
      <input type="text" class="input" name="fname">
      <p></p>
      <input type="button" value="Submit" class="submit_btn">
    </form>
  </div>

  <!-- GREETING RE NAME -->
  <div class="question" id="item2">
    HI THERE
  </div>



</div>
```

Actually, your `append()` DOES work. You had two problems in your fiddle:

1. You had `onLoad` selected. This causes all the code to be inside a `window.onload` function, so it wasn't in the global scope, which is needed for functions used in `onsubmit` attributes. Using `No wrap` fixes this.
2. You weren't preventing the default submission. Beside the way I did this above, you can also do it by simply returning `false` in the `onsubmit`:

   ```
   onsubmit="doit(); return false;"
   ```

Demo:

```js
var greeting = "hello "
var div = document.getElementById('#item2');

function doit() {
  $('#item2').append(document.name_form.fname.value + "U WOT");
}


// alert(greeting + document.name_form.fname.value)
//
//
// $( " HEYTHERDUDE "  + document.name_form.fname.value).appendTo($( " #item2 " )); 
//
// div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + 'LOOK AT ME' + document.name_form.fname.value;
```

```css
/***************************/


/*****CONTAINER STYLES******/


/***************************/

body {
  background-color: #212130;
}

#container {
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  color: #c5c520;
  font-weight: 300;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 225px;
  max-width: 325px;
}


/***************************/


/*******INPUT STYLES********/


/***************************/

.input {
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
  border-color: #c5c520;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.2s;
  -o-transition: box-shadow 0.2s;
  transition: box-shadow 0.2s;
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  color: #c5c520;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.input:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -10px 20px -10px #131322;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -10px 20px -10px #131322;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -10px 20px border-right-width: 1px;
  border-left-color: #181825;
  border-right-color: #181825;
}

.input:focus {
  background-color: #191929;
}

.name_submit {
  color: #181825;
  background-color: #c5c520;
  border: none;
}

.submit_btn {
  display: none;
}

.question {
  display: block;
  bottom: 15px;
}


/***********************************/


/*******ITEM SPECIFIC STYLES********/


/***********************************/

#item1 {
  display: block;
}

#item2 {
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">


  <!-- WHAT IS YOUR NAME -->

  <div class="question" id="item1">
    <div class="text">
      <p>
        Before we get started, what is your name?
      </p>
    </div>
    <form name="name_form" action="" onSubmit="doit(); return false">
      <input type="text" class="input" name="fname">
      <p></p>
      <input type="button" value="Submit" class="submit_btn">
    </form>
  </div>

  <!-- GREETING RE NAME -->
  <div class="question" id="item2">
    HI THERE
  </div>



</div>
```

Comment: Well append can be used to add text nodes as well.

Comment: True, but then you have to actually create a text node. If the argument is a string, it's parsed as HTML if it begins with a tag, otherwise it's treated as a selector.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the function doit is not available when you bind onsubmit.

You can try to declare doit like a variable:

```
doit = function(){
```

By the way, if you don't want to submit really the form you can bind onclick instead of onsubmit.

Code snippet:

```js
var greeting = "hello "
var div = document.getElementById('#item2');

doit = function() {
  $('#item2').append(document.name_form.fname.value + "U WOT");
  return false;
}


// alert(greeting + document.name_form.fname.value)
//
//
// $( " HEYTHERDUDE "  + document.name_form.fname.value).appendTo($( " #item2 " )); 
//
// div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + 'LOOK AT ME' + document.name_form.fname.value;
```

```css
/***************************/


/*****CONTAINER STYLES******/


/***************************/

body {
  background-color: #212130;
}

#container {
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  color: #c5c520;
  font-weight: 300;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 225px;
  max-width: 325px;
}


/***************************/


/*******INPUT STYLES********/


/***************************/

.input {
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
  border-color: #c5c520;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.2s;
  -o-transition: box-shadow 0.2s;
  transition: box-shadow 0.2s;
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  color: #c5c520;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.input:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -10px 20px -10px #131322;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -10px 20px -10px #131322;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -10px 20px border-right-width: 1px;
  border-left-color: #181825;
  border-right-color: #181825;
}

.input:focus {
  background-color: #191929;
}

.name_submit {
  color: #181825;
  background-color: #c5c520;
  border: none;
}

.submit_btn {
  display: none;
}

.question {
  display: block;
  bottom: 15px;
}


/***********************************/


/*******ITEM SPECIFIC STYLES********/


/***********************************/

#item1 {
  display: block;
}

#item2 {
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">


  <!-- WHAT IS YOUR NAME -->

  <div class="question" id="item1">
    <div class="text">
      <p>
        Before we get started, what is your name?
      </p>
    </div>
    <form name="name_form" action="#" onSubmit="doit()">
      <input type="text" class="input" name="fname">
      <p></p>
      <input type="button" value="Submit" class="submit_btn">
    </form>
  </div>

  <!-- GREETING RE NAME -->
  <div class="question" id="item2">
    HI THERE
  </div>



</div>
```

Comment: All he had to do in the fiddle was change from "onLoad" to "No Wrap" in the menu