# Append an element with fade in effect [jQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
var html = "<div id='blah'>Hello stuff here</div>"

$("#mycontent").append(html).fadeIn(999);
```

This doesn't seem to work.

I just want a cool effect when the content gets appended.

Note: I want just the new "blah" div to fade in, not the entire "mycontent".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using fadein and append](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327682/using-fadein-and-append)

Answer (score 272, accepted):

```
$(html).hide().appendTo("#mycontent").fadeIn(1000);
```

Comment: I want just the new "blah" div to fade in.

Comment: @TIMEX: That's what this should do.

Comment: Is there a reason you first hide then append (because it's faster to first set a style before attaching to the DOM, or something like that) or does it not make a difference?

Comment: @qwertymk: There's no real reason. If browsers ever rendered while the DOM was still being manipulated (which no browser currently does as far as I know), there wouldn't be any flash of the content before it started fading in. Again, not really important.

Comment: I don't 100% get why this works but thank you very much.

Comment: Actually, it **is** important to use hide() first (or equivalent) because fadeIn() won't work on an item unless it is hidden/display set to none. See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lfs1Lg9o/1/).

Comment: @EF0: I think you misunderstood the discussion; the question was not whether `hide` was required or not, but whether it must come before or after the `appendTo`. (Verdict: it shouldn’t matter.)

Comment: My bad - rereading it now I see that. Will leave my comment in case it adds value for a future reader by making it clear(er) why the `hide()` is important - wherever it's placed before the `fadeIn()`.

Comment: Brilliant! Yet, you can do `$('#blah').hide().appendTo('#blah').fadeIn(1000);` if you only want your div to fade in

Comment: @ArthurTarasov: That appends `#blah` to itself, which doesn't seem like something you want to do (and I'm guessing it's interpreted as a no-op). You might as well just drop the `.appendTo` part and use `$('#mycontent').hide().fadeIn(1000)`.

Answer (score 54):

Adding a little more info:

jQuery implements "method chaining", which means you can chain method calls on the same element. In the first case:

```
$("#mycontent").append(html).fadeIn(999);
```

you would be applying the `fadeIn` call to the object which is target of the method chain, in this case `#mycontent`. Not what you want.

In @icktoofay's (great) answer you have:

```
$(html).hide().appendTo("#mycontent").fadeIn(1000);
```

This basically means, create the `html`, set it as hidden by default, append it to `#mycontent` and **then** fade it in. The target of the method chain now is `hmtl` instead of `#mycontent`.

Answer (score 22):

This also works

```
$(Your_html).appendTo(".target").hide().fadeIn(300);
```

Regards

Comment: This is the most aesthetically pleasing way to handle fading in as it allows for the HTML to be fully composed and create the dimensions it needs before fading in.

Answer (score 0):

since the fadeIn is a transition from hide to show, you'll have to hide the "html" element when you append it and then to show it.

```js
var html = "<div id='blah'>Hello stuff here</div>"

$("#mycontent").append(function(){
  return html.hide();
});

$('#blah').fadeIn(999);
```