# Fade In Document Fragment

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm using a technique from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4687589/723007) for fading in an appended element with jQuery:

```
$(html).hide().appendTo("#mycontent").fadeIn(1000);
```

And trying to apply it to a document fragment:

```
var docfrag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    div = document.createElement('div');

div.textContent = 'Fade This In';
docfrag.appendChild(div);
```

But when I try to fade in the fragment:

```
$(docfrag).hide().appendTo('#container').fadeIn();
```

I get this error from jQuery:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'cur' of undefined
```

Does anyone know how to fade in the document fragment?

--

Trying to fade in appended **list items**? See [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19074388/723007) below.

Comment: A jsfiddl reproducing this problem will be helpful

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/V5G6g/1/

Comment: Read [this](http://james.padolsey.com/stuff/jQueryBookThing/#doc-fragments)

Comment: The fragment is just a container, and only the content of the fragment is appended, so you have to target the div inside the fragment -> http://jsfiddle.net/K6Jfe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('docfrag')` is a DocumentFragment, which has no `hide()`.

Here is the revised code in jsFiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/blaise_liu/7UwX5/)

Reason:

DocumentFragments are DOM Nodes. They are in memory when created and never part of the main DOM tree. Which means jQuery selector will not return as expected a DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't specify this in my question, but the document fragment I'm appending is a series of list items.

Since the list is already rendered with other items, I didn't have the option of fading in a container div the way [Blaise](http://jsfiddle.net/blaise_liu/7UwX5/) and [adeneo](http://jsfiddle.net/K6Jfe/) do in their fiddles.

Fading in the container `<ul>` would mean fading in the entire list, including the items already there. And I couldn't add another container for just the new list items without breaking the markup or making it really messy.

My [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/K6Jfe/8/) is a bit hack-ish but gets the job done. This is for a Backbone.js application, so the code here is simplified (and ugly) to get the basic point across without all the Backbone stuff.

```
var docfrag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    item1 = document.createElement('li'),
    item2 = document.createElement('li');

item1.textContent = 'New List Item 1';
item2.textContent = 'New List Item 2';

docfrag.appendChild(item1);
docfrag.appendChild(item2);

$item1 = $(item1);
$item2 = $(item2);

$item1.addClass('hidden').hide();
$item2.addClass('hidden').hide();

$('#button').on('click', function() {
    $(docfrag).appendTo('#list');
    $('#list').find('.hidden').fadeIn();
});
```

Once the new list items are accessible to jQuery (in my case, after running `render()` on their Backbone views), I hide them and add a class hook for fading them in later.