# jQuery table fadeIn not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

My table does not seem to fade in when the input box is checked.

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var weightSetArray = ["HH_Cancer", "Global Warming", "Acidification", "HH_Respiratory", "HH_Noncancer", "Ozone Depletion", "Eutrophication", "Smog", "Embodied Energy", "Land Use", "Water Consumption", "Sum"];
$("#weightsetcheckbox").click(function () {
    if ($("#weightsetcheckbox").is(':checked')) {
        $("#weightsetContainer").append("<table class=table id=weightsetTable></table>");
        $.each(weightSetArray, function (index, value) {
            name = value;
            name = name.replace(/\s+/g, '');
            $("#weightsetTable").append('<tr><td>' + value + '</td><td><input type=number min=0 max=100 placeholder=0 name=name></td></tr>');
        });
        $("#weightsetTable").fadeIn('slow');
    }
    else {
        $('#weightsetTable').remove();
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687579/append-an-element-with-fade-in-effect-jquery

Comment: can you provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ ?