# Fade in new posts above old ones with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to fade in new posts from my database. I have a div that contains all old posts which are loaded when the page loads, and then I want new posts to fade in above the old ones.

I just got started with jQuery. I´ve tried a few things.

This code doesn't work. (Which maybe is obvious to you.)

```
$('#oldMessages').html($('#oldMessages').html() + load('newPosts.php').hide().fadeIn(3000));
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you please give us more context of your code to understand better what you wanted to do ? And please tel us what you tried and what does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the page loads (or whenever you need to load posts), try this

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'newPosts.php',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
        // assuming data is the html of your posts
        $(data).hide().prependTo($('#oldMessages')).fadeIn(3000);
        // this will fadeIn the entire response
    }
});
```

### Edit

*This is a little hacky--the code has a couple requirements:*

1. An element (you could hide it if you wanted) with `class="timePosted"` with each post
2. That is *immediately* followed by a tag that contains the text for elapsed time with `class="timeElapsed"`. If you can't do this, I think you'll need an array with some id's to identify each post

Since you also need to update the elapsed times, you could try this inside your `success` callback function:

```
$.each($('.timePosted'), function() {
    var diff = new Date() - new Date($(this).val());

    x = diff / 1000
    seconds = x % 60
    x /= 60
    minutes = x % 60
    x /= 60
    hours = x % 24
    x /= 24
    days = x

    if (days >= 1)
        $(this).next('.timeElapsed').html(days + ' days ago');
    else if (hours >= 1)
        $(this).next('.timeElapsed').html(hours + ' hours ago');
    else if (minutes >= 1)
        $(this).next('.timeElapsed').html(minutes + ' minutes ago');
    else if (seconds >= 1)
        $(this).next('.timeElapsed').html(seconds + ' seconds ago');

});
```

Comment: I found this code very useful! Thanks! I run it every fifth seconds. One problem though: I also want to update #oldMessages every now and then, how can i do that without affecting the fading?

Comment: @Daniel In what way do you need to update #oldMessages? I thought that's what this was doing?

Comment: When the page loads the first time I display all posts in #oldMessages. Every fifth second I run the code I got from you to search for new posts, and fade them above the old ones. This works perfectly. The problem is that when i display a post I also display elapsed time since the post was posted for example "2 minutes ago" or "one hour ago", that´s why I also need to update #oldMessages so that the elapsed time changes as the time goes. But I can´t do it the same time as I fade in new posts, because then the fading fails.

Comment: @Daniel Oh wow--you need to update each post on every request. Let's see...I'll try to edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I haven´t got it to work yet though. Do you mean like this: (An example) <div class="timePosted">2011-06-27 10:12:10</div><div class="timeElapsed">20 minutes ago</div>

Comment: @Daniel If you use a div for `.timePosted`, you might need `.html()` instead of `.val()`. When I tested it, I used a hidden input. So, the first line of the `.each` loop would look like: `var diff = new Date() - new Date($(this).html());` instead

Comment: Thank you! Everything works perfectly except one thing. <div class="timePosted" style="display: none;">2011-06-27 10:12:10</div>. For some reason the div displays in the posts I get from newPosts.php. Any idea why?

EDIT: I used display: none !important; which made it work. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you mean, but if you want to "pop" the new data above the old posts, you could try something like this:

HTML:

```
...
<div id="new"></div>
<div id="old"></div>
...
```

JavaScript:

```
function loadNewData(url) {
  // prepend contents of 'new' div to 'old' div contents
  $('#old').prepend($('#new').html());

  // reload 'new' div with fresh data from 'url'
  $('#new').load(url).hide().fadeIn(3000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check this question: [Using fadein and append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327682/using-fadein-and-append)

it's for a similar thing, and the solution provided most likely the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

try '**prepend**':

```
var new = $('<div id="newMessages" style="display:hidden"></div>').load('newPosts.php');
$('#oldMessages').prepend(new);
$('#newMessages').fadeIn(3000);
```

sorry, code updated