# How to slide down in javascript if the data posted

Tags: javascript

I build a code here.. that when he\she posts a comment the JavaScript will slide down a new comment block...

But i need to refresh after click the post button - then - there will be a new comment block under a post.

This is my code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
//Sending the jquery comment
function SendComment(blab_id) {
    var comment_txt = $("#Comment"+blab_id).val()

    if(comment_txt == ""){
    alert("Please Enter a Comment!");
    }else{

    $.post("scripts/send_comment.php", {Comment: comment_txt, bid: blab_id} ,function(data){

    $("#new_comment"+blab_id).html(data);
    $("#new_comment"+blab_id).slideDown(300);
    $("#Comment"+blab_id).val("");

    });

    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: What is the problem?  What does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: Does $("#new_comment"+blab_id).html(data); exist on the page? I don't think you can just randomly add containers like that...

Comment: @cosmorogers sorry i didn't put the container in this div... could you please correct this code
<div style="background-color:#f0f9fe";border-bottom:1px dashed #3A69B6; padding:5px; width:auto;"><strong>'.$comment_user.'
</strong><br/>'.$comment_txt.' <br/> ·'.$whenComment.'·</div>

Answer (score 0):

assuming your script works fine, except that u need to refresh page every time...

why cant you automatically refresh that particular div without loading overall page like this...

$('#Comment"+blab_id).load('yourpage.php');

Answer (score 0):

What is "#Comment"+blab_id ? If that is just an input field, what is blab_id?

I think what you want is something like http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form , but instead of a table a bunch of divs. I would have one div id=comments that contains all the comments, then you should be able to add more comments to the bottom of this. So instead of

```
$("#new_comment"+blab_id).html(data);
$("#new_comment"+blab_id).slideDown(300);
```

you would have `$("comments").append(data).fadeIn();` (According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327682/using-fadein-and-append)) (Or [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) if you want the comment to appear at the top) (I haven't checked if this works though...)

where I assume data is

```
<div style="background-color:#f0f9fe";border-bottom:1px dashed #3A69B6; padding:5px; width:auto;">
    <strong>'.$comment_user.' </strong>
    <br/>'.$comment_txt.' <br/> ·'.$whenComment.'·
</div>
```

which is returned from scripts/send_comment.php